# Reusing /copying Macros from a file to another file

Tags: excel, vba, savefiledialog

I have an issue where I take data from multiple files and copy it into my current file. I work with the data and now I need to create a new File that contains the macros and the "style" from one of the import files and the new data I created.

So basically I take a file, delete all data from it. Then take my data and paste it into the file. Later I save the combinations of macros from old file and new data into a new file with which is created with the name "save as dialog."

So far I have a working import for all of the files and also my work on the data is doing great. Only this export is missing.

My idea would be to make the Path of the file public during the import and then during the import file use this path to do the following:

- copy this file,
- delete all data besides the macros and buttons
- copy my data into it.
- open the "save as dialog and let the user choose a name and the location where to save it.

However, I have absolutely no idea how something like this could be done in terms of code. Some code examples with explanations would be all I need I hope that I can then tailor it to fit my needs.

This is the code I tried so far but it's just a regular "save my current file" that doesn't include any macros from another file or takes another file as basis.

```
Sub DateiSpeichern()
    Dim StandardPfad As String
    Dim ExportBlatt As Worksheet
    Dim NeueDatei As Workbook

    StandardPfad = "C:\X"

    Set NeueDatei = Workbooks.Add
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Test").Copy Before:=NeueDatei.Sheets(1)
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    Sheets(2).Delete
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True

    'displays the save file dialog
    StandardPfad = Application.GetSaveAsFilename(FileFilter:= _
      "Exceldateien (*.xlsx), *.xlsx", Title:="Datei speichern", _
      InitialFileName:="")

   NeueDatei.SaveCopyAs Filename:=StandardPfad

   NeueDatei.Close savechanges:=False
End Sub
```

---

Hello,

here is my first attempt of coding it. It doesnt work but i hope I got atleast the right idea.

```
Sub DateiSpeichern()
        Dim StandardPfad As String
        Dim ExportBlatt As Worksheet
        Dim NeueDatei As Workbook
        Dim VorlagenDatei As Workbook

'Sets a default directory
StandardPfad = "C:\Test"

'opens the dialog to choose the template file.
Set VorlagenDatei = Workbooks.Open(StandardPfad)

StandardPfad = Application.GetSaveAsFilename(FileFilter:= _
        "Exceldateien (*.xlsx), *.xlsx", Title:="Datei speichern", _
        InitialFileName:="")

'copies the selected file (something is wrong here i would assume)
VorlagenDatei.SaveCopyAs Filename:=StandardPfad

'copies my worksheet (Test) into the newly generated (copied) file. Here I need to somehow specifie the range where it is copied to.
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Tires").Copy Before:=NeueDatei.Sheets(1)
```

Comment: The easiest way would be to import your data into the file with the desired macros (template) and save it with SaveAs. So you don't copy the macros but the data. This is much easier to achieve.

Comment: Make the macros a add-in. That way any file will have access to the macros

Comment: Hey, thanks for your help. Unfortunatly Iam not allowed to change the macros and also they are in development so I always need to copy the current version of the macros. So the state of the macros has to be the same as the state of the data. Because of this I cant really save the Macros once and reuse them, they are specific to the (changing) file that is importat at the beginning. Unfortunatly :/

Comment: @G.M Then still: Make a copy of the macro file and *import* the desired data into that file, instead of import the macros into the data file. It is much easier to copy data than to copy macros.

Comment: @Pᴇʜ sorry maybe I got you wrong the first time, but thats is exactly what I want :D copy the macro file and import the data. But how? One "Open FIle" Dialog to choose it and then another one to choose where to save it. But how can i (for example) copy the macro file?

Comment: just open your macro file with `Set MyTemplate = Workbooks.Open("C:\MyMacroFile.xlsm")` and push in your data eg `ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Test").Copy Before:=MyTemplate.Sheets(1)`. Then ask for a filename with `GetSaveAsFilename` and use `MyTemplate.SaveAs` to save. That's all.

Comment: Sounds like you are inventing the wheel each time some data comes in. Generally, you can account for slight variations in the data such as what column some data is in and if some data is missing. Maybe that is the route to go instead?

Comment: I made a attempt at coding it but so far no succes ^^"